# Remove Duplicate Dynamic Range, Keeping First, Using Split Based on Specific String

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, duplicates

I have some somewhat unique data(yes, all data is unique) that I'm trying to parse through and remove duplicate ranges but keeping the first unique range. I don't see anyway to sort the data as it is all single column but sectioned. An example of the data is below:

```
SSID 18 : NewThermostat_552845
Network type            : Infrastructure
Authentication          : Open
Encryption              : None 
BSSID 1                 : 00:d0:2d:55:28:45
     Signal             : 78%  
     Radio type         : 802.11n
     Channel            : 6 
     Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 6 11 12 24
     Other rates (Mbps) : 9 18 36 48 54

SSID 24 : 
Network type            : Infrastructure
Authentication          : Open
Encryption              : None 
BSSID 1                 : f8:bb:bf:59:56:89
     Signal             : 35%  
     Radio type         : 802.11n
     Channel            : 1 
     Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 11
     Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54

SSID 11 : NewThermostat_552845
Network type            : Infrastructure
Authentication          : Open
Encryption              : None 
BSSID 1                 : 00:d0:2d:55:28:45
     Signal             : 94%  
     Radio type         : 802.11n
     Channel            : 6 
     Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.5 6 11 12 24
     Other rates (Mbps) : 9 18 36 48 54
```

The SSID ## is the beginning of each new section. By my code below, you can see the various things I've tried. I've commented out things that didn't work but might work in a different combination. I used the MsgBox and copy/paste for debugging so that is not needed in the final code.

Here's the code I'm working with.

```
'need to split the cell
dRow = newSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set dString = newSht.Range("A1:A" & dRow)
For Each cel In dString
    If cel.Value Like "SSID ## : *" Then
        'If cel.Value = cel.Value Then
        theSplit = Split(cel.Value, ":")(0)(1)
        'If theSplit(1) = theSplit(1) Then
        If theSplit(0) Like theSplit(-1) Then 'And cel.Value(0) = cel.Value(0) Then
            'cel.Value(1).Copy
            'Range("F1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            MsgBox cel.Value

            'Range(cel, cel.End(xlDown)).Delete
            'cel.Value(1).Copy Range("F1")
            'Range(cel, cel.End(xlDown)).Delete
        End If
    End If
    'End If
Next cel
```

I'm thinking the best approach is to split each instance of SSID ## at the : sign. Then if any of the 2nd part of the string matches, delete the range from SSID ## down to the blank cell. Currently my code deletes everything! Thanks in advance for your insight! Much appreciated!

Comment: In your provided sample data, are there any duplicates?  It looks like each section would be considered unique (since the SSID #s are all different) so nothing would be deleted.

Comment: The duplicates I'm looking for are based on the string after the ':' so essentially both SSID 18 : NewThermostat_552845 and SSID 11 : NewThermostat_552845 are duplicates.

Comment: I would probably try to do some ETL in Excel first, then if it all needs to be in VBA, replicate that in VBA. Do the column split at `:` (though that could pose a problem in certain rows, but there are ways around it), flag all your sections with a unique value in a separate column (ie the headers name), and another flag for each header row. Now you should be able to search for duplicates, and use the extra information to eliminate them... Obviously not a full proof solution, but that's what I would look at first.

Comment: @ToddCoplien For those entries, there is a slight difference in their "blocks", the `Signal` is 78% for the first one and 94% for the second.  Which one should be retained?  I'm guessing only the first one since it was encountered first?

Comment: @tigeravatar Yes, the signal is different based on where I was in the building when I was grabbing the data. And yes, I would like to keep the first entry only no matter the signal strength. Unless that helps parsing through the data.

Comment: @tigeravatar and anyone else, I have another question based on this as it has come to light that I should be keeping the duplicate that has the highest signal strength. Not sure what I was thinking. Should I ask a new question or can we add to this one? I don't mind either way! TY

Comment: @ToddCoplien See updated answer.

Comment: @tigeravatar sorry for not responding sooner. didn't realize you replied. thank you very much. way cleaner than what I came up! thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim rAllRegions As Range
    Dim rRegion As Range
    Dim rDel As Range
    Dim hSSID As Object
    Dim sSSID As String

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rData = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Set rAllRegions = GetAllPopulatedCells(, rData)
    Set hSSID = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    If rAllRegions Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No populated cells found in '" & ws.Name & "'. Exiting Macro.", , "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each rRegion In rAllRegions.Areas
        sSSID = LCase(Trim(Split(rRegion.Cells(1).Value, ":")(1)))
        If Not hSSID.exists(sSSID) Then
            hSSID.Add sSSID, sSSID
        Else
            If rDel Is Nothing Then Set rDel = rRegion.Resize(rRegion.Rows.Count + 1) Else Set rDel = Union(rDel, rRegion.Resize(rRegion.Rows.Count + 1))
        End If
    Next rRegion

    If Not rDel Is Nothing Then rDel.Delete xlShiftUp

End Sub

Public Function GetAllPopulatedCells(Optional ByRef arg_ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal arg_rSearchRange As Range) As Range

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rSearch As Range
    Dim rConstants As Range
    Dim rFormulas As Range

    If arg_ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet Else Set ws = arg_ws
    If arg_rSearchRange Is Nothing Then Set rSearch = ws.Cells Else Set rSearch = arg_rSearchRange

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rConstants = rSearch.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set rFormulas = rSearch.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case Abs(rConstants Is Nothing) + 2 * Abs(rFormulas Is Nothing)
        Case 0: Set GetAllPopulatedCells = Union(rConstants, rFormulas)
        Case 1: Set GetAllPopulatedCells = rFormulas
        Case 2: Set GetAllPopulatedCells = rConstants
        Case 3: Set GetAllPopulatedCells = Nothing
    End Select

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set rSearch = Nothing
    Set rConstants = Nothing
    Set rFormulas = Nothing

End Function
```

**UPDATE**: This version will keep only the highest signal strength blocks for each region (note you will still need the GetAllPopulatedCells function)

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim rAllRegions As Range
    Dim rRegion As Range
    Dim rDel As Range
    Dim rTemp as Range
    Dim hSSID As Object
    Dim sSSID As String
    Dim lSSIDRow as Long
    Dim lSignalRow as Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rData = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Set rAllRegions = GetAllPopulatedCells(, rData)
    Set hSSID = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lSSIDRow = 1
    lSignalRow = 6

    If rAllRegions Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No populated cells found in '" & ws.Name & "'. Exiting Macro.", , "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each rRegion In rAllRegions.Areas
        sSSID = LCase(Trim(Split(rRegion.Cells(lSSIDRow, 1).Value, ":")(1)))
        If Not hSSID.exists(sSSID) Then
            Set hSSID(sSSID) = rRegion
        Else
            If --Trim(Split(hSSID(sSSID).Cells(lSignalRow, 1).Value, ":")(1)) > --Trim(Split(rRegion.Cells(lSignalRow, 1).Value, ":")(1)) Then
                Set rTemp = rRegion.Resize(rRegion.Rows.Count + 1)
            Else
                Set rTemp = hSSID(sSSID)
                Set hSSID(sSSID) = rRegion
            End If
            If rDel Is Nothing Then Set rDel = rTemp Else Set rDel = Union(rDel, rTemp)
        End If
    Next rRegion

    If Not rDel Is Nothing Then rDel.Delete xlShiftUp

End Sub
```